# No keyboard or mouse when first starting Ubuntu installation, stuck at screen with keyboard = man in circle

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I'm trying to install ubuntu on a vm using virtual box.  I set it up and start the vm and it gets stuck at a purple screen with a keyboard symbol, equals symbol, and then a symbol of a man in a circle.  My keyboard and mouse are usb.  I've tried sticking them into different usb slots to no avail.

Edit: I added virtual box extensions for usb and tried to set the usb controller to  usb 1, 2, or 3 but then the VM would not start at all.

Edit #2: Reinstalled latest virtual box with extensions.  I've tried with and without filter for the keyboard, but nothing works.  Tried it with Kali Linux as well.  128MB video ram, 4mb base memory 2 processors.  All out of ideas.

Edit #3: Bought some usb to PS/2 adapters to see if maybe the mouse and keyboard will work using that input.  Wish me luck.

Comment: Have you validated the ISO as being perfect?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)

Comment: @guiverc Yes I have

Answer (score 0):

(https://www.dell.com) Go to the PC manufacturer and get the windows drivers.Your new OS will install the windows installer for the correct driver. After the system does it's thing . Restart the computer.

Comment: Use other os info. I'm working with Zorin.But l go to other sites to see what works best. Also install wine in the terminal that's what makes it work

Comment: The mouse and keyboard work fine in Windows 10, just not in the VM.  I don't understand how getting drivers would help the Ubuntu VM

Answer (score 0):

Your described screen is Ubuntu installation *loading screen* and your mouse & keyboard won't be functional in this screen, so don't play your VM settings ... Probably your hardware resources are low or the VM dedicated with low resources ... anyway, It is a Virtual Machine and usually processing operations are significantly slower on these environments. Maybe increasing the VM memory resource help you and be more patient when the screen appeared.

Comment: I've used Ubuntu on VMs before on other computers with 0 problems.  Well not 0, but problems I could fix.  I increased the VM memory to 128, base memory to 5981, processors equal to 4